# Spring Boot App & React App Cannot Communicate Inside Openshift

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, openshift

I have deployed a single fat .jar, containing a Spring Boot app and a React app in Openshift.
The Spring Boot app exposes a REST API, and the React app is the frontend that makes calls to that API.

#### Problem

Both apps are accessible externally just fine (with the url generated by Openshift), but the React app cannot communicate with the Spring Boot app through `http://localhost:8080/...` calls.

#### Attempts so Far

- I have tried using `127.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` but with no avail.
- I also tried performing `curl -v http://localhost:8080/...` from *inside* the pod where the 2 apps are deployed and *it works fine*.

Is this a configuration issue? Do I need to set up routes? Or use something other than `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Just use relative URLs

Comment: Can you post your `Deployment` / `DeploymentConfig` and `Service` you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I finally managed to solve this by following Boris Chistov's suggestion. I simply removed all the `http://localhost:8080` url parts and used relative URLs instead.